# Find $\gcd(2x+7, x^2-2)=d(x)$ where all polynomials are in $\Bbb Q[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

So, I used the Euclidean Algorithm to solve for the GCD:

$x^2-2=(2x+7)(\frac12x-\frac74)+\frac{41}4$

$2x+7=\frac{41}4(\frac8{41}x+\frac{28}{41})+0$

$\therefore \gcd(x^2-2,2x+7)=\frac{41}4$

---

However, this is obviously not true, and I checked this multiple times. So, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the gcd turned out to be $x^3-5x+4$, that's the same as saying that it's $2x^3-10x+8$.  In this context, "greatest" in the phrase "greatest common divisor" means having the greatest *degree* among common divisors.  The two polynomials I give above are scalar multiples of each other and are therefore treated as equivalent (multiply the first by $2$ to get the second or multiply the second by $1/2$ to get the first).

Consider finding gcd's among integers $0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\ldots\,{}$.  Is $\gcd(24,18)$ equal to $6$ or to $-6$?  You can get either of those numbers from the other by multiplying it by a member of the set $\{0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\ldots\}$, namely by $-1$.  Therefore they're treated as equivalent.  But $6$ is not equivalent to $12$ since you cannot multiply $12$ by any member of $\{0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\ldots\}$ and get $6$.

Among non-zero rational numbers, all are equivalent.

Sometimes one adopts the convention of regarding the *monic* polynomial among the possibilities as being the answer.  "Monic" means the leading coefficient is $1$, so in the example above it would be $x^3-5x+4$ and not $2$ times that.

Thus $41/4$ and $1$ are equivalent since you can get either from the other by multiplying it by some rational number, but the *monic* polynomial among them is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as 1 being the Gcd. In the rationals, $1\mid \frac{41}{4}$.

Comment: That makes $\frac{41}4$ a bigger divisor than 1. How can you say that they're the same?

Answer (score 0):

More pertinently, you're indicating that the two polynomials are relatively prime. And this is true.

One way of seeing this would be to actually pretend you were working in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Then the first polynomial is $(x + \sqrt 2)(x - \sqrt 2)$, and the second is $2(x + \frac{7}{2})$. These clearly have no linear factors $(x - a)$ in common, and are thus clearly relatively prime.

Comment: How am I indicating that they are relatively prime?

Comment: Because their gcd is $41/4$, which is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes much more sense. Thanks!